# Objective C - How to put a close button in window?

Tags: objective-c, button, window

I'm having a problem on putting a close button in my window in objective C, I have created the button, but I don't know what the method I need to call to close the window, I have done this:

```
    -(void)awakeFromNib{

//Create a button
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(350, 10, 100, 50);
    NSButton *btn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [btn setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
    [btn setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
    [btn setTitle:@"Close"];
    [btn setTarget:self];
    [btn setAction:@selector(closeWindow)];
    [view addSubview:btn];



}


-(void)closeWindow{}
```

I don't know what to put in close window method

Answer (score 2):

You can close the current window by using something along these lines:

```
NSWindow *window = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window close];
```

However, this does not actively simulate a user closing a window, since it does not call delegate methods, nor does it highlight the close button. You may want to use this instead:

```
NSWindow *window = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window performClose:sender];
```

In that case, you'd probably want pass your button as the sender. You can receive the button in your `closeWindow` method as an object to make things simple.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing it from your NSWindowController subclass, just call `[self close]`.

Answer (score -1):

If you touch a view to current this view, you can use removeFromSuperview.
Just simple add [self removeFromSuperview];